# (Install xk6) How to fix PATH issue when install xk6 use go

Tags: go, prometheus, k6

When I followed the [k6 doc](https://k6.io/docs/results-visualization/prometheus/). and installed xk6 to enable Prometheus, I found the following error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVbRQ.png)

I feel like I am missing something super basic.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to outdated documentation, which will be fixed shortly.

You can install xk6 with `go install go.k6.io/xk6/cmd/xk6@latest`. See the [installation instructions in the GitHub repository](https://github.com/grafana/xk6#install).

Apologies for the confusion. In the future please use the [community forum](https://community.k6.io/c/extensions/11) for these types of questions, since it's not on topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the instructions are obsolete: if you see the doc on the github repo, the command is:

```
>go install go.k6.io/xk6/cmd/xk6@latest
go: downloading go.k6.io/xk6 v0.5.0
go: downloading github.com/Masterminds/semver/v3 v3.1.0
```

UPDATE: The instruction has  been already updated https://github.com/grafana/k6-docs/commit/fa7115d00d1f04c95047dedb37e3613602465bda